# How do you verify a Firebase Function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-hosting, google-cloud-pubsub

I'd like to add a webhook to a Google Cloud PubSub push subscription. My endpoint for the webhook url is a Firebase Function. To post to my Firebase endpoint, I must verify the domain.

My problem is that Firebase Functions don't seem to have a way to statically host a single website. Firebase hosting happens in an entirely different domain.

What I *have* (from Firebase Hosting):

> https://[PROJECT-ID].firebaseapp.com/[GOOGLE-FILE].html

What I *need* (from Firebase Functions):

> https://us-central1-[PROJECTID].cloudfunctions.net/[Google-FILE].html

Comment: What are you looking at that suggests pubsub triggers require domain verification?  I've been able to set up and use pubsub triggers in Cloud Functions without any hassle (other than activating billing, as required).

Comment: A pull subscription requires domain verification.

Comment: Are you trying to set up a function to get triggered whenever a message lands in a pubsub topic?  Share some code?

Comment: Following this guide: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#watch_request

Comment: There really isn't code to share; it's a setup step - verification.

Comment: I can imagine that if you try to set up a webhook callback, it will want to make sure you own the domain, but for pubsub topic messaging, there is no such thing.

Comment: I'm setting up for webhook callback, per the guide.

Comment: Ok, your question states pubsub in both the text and the tag. You may want to consider rewriting it. Or, actually use pubsub which should be much easier.

Comment: I don't follow your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Rewrote question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using `express.static` on a folder containing Google's HTML to be verified in my "./functions" directory.

Google really ought to consider allowing their static site hosting to optionally deploy to a specified route in a *functions* domain, rather than purely through a separate domain.

Something like the following:

```
...
constructor() {
    this.express = express();

    // place your google verification HMTL file in the directory to expose
    // in my case, 'www'
    this.express.use(express.static(join(__dirname, '../..', 'www')));
```

Then deploy your function.

Comment: Is it possible to get more details on how you achieved that? Thx!

Comment: @Jefftopia would you please add step to step solution, for example where are you creating that `www` in your project and how did you deploy it to firebase functions?

Comment: @Reza Look closely at my `express.static` - I'm resolving the path to my www directory. The directory location doesn't matter, you pass the path to it to the method. It's a standard `firebase deploy`, there's nothing special about it.

Comment: Thanks, I found another solution as well, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/57793056/2279488