# How to setup google pub/sub subscription to call firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to have a `push` subscription, but when I try to add this `firebase function` `https://us-central1-myproject-dev.cloudfunctions.net/api/conversation` as Endpoint Url, it says

> The supplied URL is not registered in the subscription's parent project. Please see documentation on domain ownership validation .

The problem is I can't verify that `https://us-central1-myproject-dev.cloudfunctions.net` is my domain, which of course is not

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried [using the Pub/Sub trigger type](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events) instead of manually configuring a trigger?

Comment: @MichaelBleigh the issue with that approach is it only accepts topics from same project, my topic is on other project and I want to subscribe to it, so I have to . create a push subscription and call the endpoint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution in case any body else has same issue

1) When adding a property in Google Search Console, select the method `URL prefix` and enter the url of the function you will create in step 3 (i.e. `https://my-project.cloudfunctions.net/googleDomainVerification`).

2) Select the method `HTML tag` and copy the meta-tag.

3) Create a https function that you push on Firebase Cloud Function. Don't forget to copy your meta-tag from step 2:

```
    exports.googleDomainVerification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send('<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> YOUR_META_TAG_HERE </head> <body> </body> </html>')
    })
```

4) Wait a minute then press "Verify" on the Google Search Console

Done! now you can use `https://my-project.cloudfunctions.net/googleDomainVerification` or `https://my-project.cloudfunctions.net/googleDomainVerification/mysubfunction` in subscription

Comment: How does one deploy `mySubFunction` to respond at `.net/googleDomainVerification/mySubFunction`, rather than `.net/mySubFunction`? Getting the function to attach under the `googleDomainVerification` namespace is proving a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

Took me half a day but I finally noticed that Google adds a "/" to the end of the endpoint URL when adding it to the domain verification function.

After verifying your endpoint URL as stated above:

1. In your Google Cloud Platform go to API & Services
2. Go to Domain Verification
3. Add your verified endpoint URL to the project.
4. Note that if your endpoint URL is https://aaa/bbb/ccc Google will add it to the verified domains as aaa/bbb/ccc/
5. When creating a push subscription, enter aaa/bbb/ccc/ as your endpoint URL.